# Getting error for showing the charts under iframe from superset for public website, error says CSRF token doesn't match

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, apache-superset

I have a problem of showing the chart from superset on the public website or web space.
As per the given instructions on the superset documentation, I had updated few of the settings present on the `config.py` file but to my situation that didn't improve my situation and I got error like `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"> <title>400 Bad Request</title> <h1>Bad Request</h1> <p>The CSRF tokens do not match.</p>`

**This issue is coming on intermittently** not all the time.
So Actions I have performed are:

1. Updated the public role to allow all the charts to be displayed, datasources, 
   *[can userinfo on UserDBModelView, can list on UserDBModelView, can show on UserDBModelView, can list on SliceModelView, can show on SliceModelView, can list on DashboardModelView, can show on DashboardModelView, can list on DatabaseView, can list on DashboardModelViewAsync, can dashboard on Superset, can explore json on Superset, menu access on Dashboards, all datasource access on all_datasource_access, datasource access on [None].SelectAllData-xxxx, datasource access on [None].SelectAllData-DRGJDcTLj, datasource access on [None].SelectAllData-xxxxx, datasource access on [superset_mysql_db].Superset Admin-SelectAllData-xxxx]*
2. Then I went inside the directory where the superset is installed and updated the settings config.py

```
   PUBLIC_ROLE_LIKE_GAMMA = True
   SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None  # One of [None, 'Lax', 'Strict']
   SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
```

But still I am getting error few a times.
Sometime one of the chart gets loaded sometimes it doesn't.

help pls!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my testing server embedding worked when I put this line in my loaded "superset_config.py" file.

```
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False
```

Comment: getting this now. ERROR: Favstar toggling denied